# React dynamic form bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created script for dynamic form, but there's 2 things which I can't get and my head is exploding right now, hopefully somebody would help me with that.

1. After creating new fields - I can't remove fields depends on button which was clicked.
2. And after removing some of those fields, I have this error with fields[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYQE3.png)

```
import React from "react";
import {useState , useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";


const Form = () =>{
  const [fieldsLength, fieldsLengthChanger] = useState(1);
  const [fields, fieldsChanger] = useState([{
    id : 1,
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    age: ""
  }])



  return  (
    <>
      <div className="form__wrapper">
        <h2>Form </h2>
        {
          fields.map((elem, index) => {
            return(
              <FormElement {...elem} fields={fields} fieldsChanger={fieldsChanger} fieldsLength={fieldsLength} fieldsLengthChanger={fieldsLengthChanger}/>
            )
          })
        }
        <AddMore fieldsLength={fieldsLength} fieldsLengthChanger={fieldsLengthChanger} fields={fields} fieldsChanger={fieldsChanger}/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}


const FormElement = ({fieldsLength  ,...props}) =>{

  function inputHandler(e, id){
    console.log(e.target.name);
    const values = [...props.fields];
    values[id-1][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    props.fieldsChanger(values);
  }

  function removeElement(e,id){
    e.preventDefault();
    var arr = [...props.fields];
    const newArray = arr.filter(function(elem,index){
      console.log("index:" , index, "ID : ", id);
      if (index + 1 != id){
        return elem;
      }
    });
    // console.log(newArray);
    // arr.splice(3, 1);
    props.fieldsChanger([])
    props.fieldsChanger(newArray);

    
  }

  return (
    <div className="group__form">
      <div className="form__element">
        <input type="text" value={props.fields.name} name="name" onChange={e => inputHandler(e , props.id)} />
      </div>
      <div className="form__element">
        <input type="text" value={props.fields.phone} name="phone" onChange={e => inputHandler(e , props.id)}/>
      </div>
      <div className="form__element">
        <input type="text" value={props.fields.age} name="age" onChange={e => inputHandler(e , props.id)}/>
      </div>
      {
        fieldsLength > 1 ? <div className="remove__field">
          <a href="#" onClick={e=>removeElement(e , props.id)}>Remove</a>
        </div> : ""
      }
    </div>
  )
}
const AddMore = (props) =>{
  function addMore(){
    props.fieldsLengthChanger(props.fields.length + 1);
    props.fieldsChanger([...props.fields, {id:props.fields.length + 1 , name: "" , phone : "" , age :''} ]);
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="add__more">
      <a href="#" onClick={e=> addMore()}>Add element</a>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Form/> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

Where I'm wrong - would be really helpfull to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You should use the `props.id` to remove a form instead of using `index`.**

e.g. this must be a bug.

```
      if (index + 1 != id) {
        return elem;
      }
```

**2. And you should use `id` by the unique value generation instead of using array's length.**

**3. You should provide the `key` prop in the render of the form fields. Otherwise, React can't distinguish forms in rendering.
And the `key` should be unique whenever you add or remove items.**

e.g. See the updated code. You need to use `elem.id`. (Of course, you should generate `id` in the add method.

```
       {fields.map((elem, index) => {
          return (
            <FormElement
              key={elem.id}
              {...elem}
              fields={fields}
              fieldsChanger={fieldsChanger}
              fieldsLength={fieldsLength}
              fieldsLengthChanger={fieldsLengthChanger}
            />
          );
        })}
```

**4. You could basically use a timestamp.** Please use your own generation logic in the production. You can use [`uuid` generation package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

```
    {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      name: "",
      phone: "",
      age: ""
    }
```

**My advices:**

1. You don't need to use this state variable `const [fieldsLength, fieldsLengthChanger] = useState(1);`
   Because we can get this value by `fields.length`.
2. There are a few problems in terms of components design. e.g. Please try to define `addMore()` in `form` then you don't need to pass `fields`, `fieldsChanger` as props.

Here is a full working code with your old code commented.

```
const Form = () => {
  const [fieldsLength, fieldsLengthChanger] = useState(1);
  const [fields, fieldsChanger] = useState([
    {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      name: "",
      phone: "",
      age: ""
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form__wrapper">
        <h2>Form </h2>
        {fields.map((elem, index) => {
          return (
            <FormElement
              key={elem.id}
              {...elem}
              fields={fields}
              fieldsChanger={fieldsChanger}
              fieldsLength={fieldsLength}
              fieldsLengthChanger={fieldsLengthChanger}
            />
          );
        })}
        <AddMore
          fieldsLength={fieldsLength}
          fieldsLengthChanger={fieldsLengthChanger}
          fields={fields}
          fieldsChanger={fieldsChanger}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const FormElement = ({ fieldsLength, ...props }) => {
  function inputHandler(e, id) {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    const values = [...props.fields];
    const item = values.find((x) => x.id === props.id);
    if (item) {
      item[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    }
    // values[id - 1][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    props.fieldsChanger(values);
  }

  function removeElement(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arr = [...props.fields];
    const newArray = arr.filter(function (elem, index) {
      /*console.log("index:", index, "ID : ", id);
      if (index + 1 != id) {
        return elem;
      }*/
      return elem.id !== id;
    });
    // console.log(newArray);
    // arr.splice(3, 1);
    props.fieldsChanger([]);
    props.fieldsChanger(newArray);
  }

  return (
    <div className="group__form">
      <div className="form__element">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.fields.name}
          name="name"
          onChange={(e) => inputHandler(e, props.id)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form__element">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.fields.phone}
          name="phone"
          onChange={(e) => inputHandler(e, props.id)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form__element">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.fields.age}
          name="age"
          onChange={(e) => inputHandler(e, props.id)}
        />
      </div>
      {fieldsLength > 1 ? (
        <div className="remove__field">
          <a href="#" onClick={(e) => removeElement(e, props.id)}>
            Remove
          </a>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
const AddMore = (props) => {
  function addMore() {
    props.fieldsLengthChanger(props.fields.length + 1);
    props.fieldsChanger([
      ...props.fields,
      //{ id: props.fields.length + 1, name: "", phone: "", age: "" }
      { id: new Date().getTime(), name: "", phone: "", age: "" }
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="add__more">
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => addMore()}>
        Add element
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use `key` when rendering list.

```
<FormElement key={elem.id} {...elem} ...
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys